# Copiar Telefono completo con codigo de Pais con extension intl-tel-input

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, google-apps-script, google-apps-script-html-service

Tengo un problema usando la extension intl-tel-input (https://github.com/jackocnr/intl-tel-input#demo-and-examples)

**Inicio los CDN:**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/intl-tel-input/12.1.5/css/intlTelInput.css">
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/intl-tel-input/12.1.5/js/intlTelInput.js"></script>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/intl-tel-input/12.1.5/js/intlTelInput.min.js"></script>
```

**Luego modifico el CSS:**

```
 .iti-flag {
background-image: url("https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/intl-tel-input/12.1.5/img/flags.png");
}
```

**En el Formulario tengo:**

```
 <tr>
  <div class="row separate">
     <td><label for="plan" class="col-sm-2">3. Phone Type:</label>
     <input id="phone" type="tel" class="form-control sized col-sm-10 separate-label">
     <script>
var input = $("#phone");

input.intlTelInput({
nationalMode: true,
autoPlaceholder: 'polite',
formatOnDisplay: 'true',
utilsScript: "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/intl-tel-input/12.1.5/js/utils.js" // just for formatting/placeholders etc
});



var intlNumber = $("#phone").intlTelInput("getNumber");
     </script>
  </div> </tr>
```

**Tengo un Parrafo donde me genera el Comentario**

```
 <div >  <!-- Second column in main row -->
 <p><b>COMMENTS:</b></p>
 <button onclick="generateComments()" id="generate" data-clipboard-target="#comment" class="btn-primary">Generate</button>
 <button onclick="resetForm(); resetPhonebox();" class="btn-primary">Reset</button>      
 <div>
 <textarea rows="10" columns="25" id="comment"></textarea>
 </div>
```

**Aqui las funciones**

```
(function(){
   new Clipboard('#generate'); })();

 function generateComments(){

     var test = $("#test").val();
     var domainn = $("#domainn").val();
     var contact = $("#contact").val();
     var intlNumber = $("#intlNumber").val();
     var timez = $("#timez").val();
     var plan = $("#plan").val();
     var domain = $("#domain").val();

//----CUSTOMER INFORMATION-----

     if(domainn != ""){
        domainn = "\n- ️ Domain Name: " + $("#domainn").val(); 
     }else{
        domainn = "";
        }

     if(contact != ""){
        contact = "\n-  Contact Name: " + $("#contact").val(); 
     }else{
        contact = "";  
        }

     if(intlNumber != ""){
        intlNumber = "\n-  Phone Number: " + $("#intlNumber").val(); 
     }else{
        intlNumber = "";  
        }

     if(timez != ""){
        timez = "\n- Time Zone: " + $("#timez").val(); 
     }else{
        timez = "";  
        }

     if(newemail != ""){
        newemail = "\n-  Email: " + $("#newemail").val(); 
     }else{
        newemail = "";  
        }            

     if(domainn != "" || contact != "" || intlNumber != "" || timez != "" || newemail != ""){
       custinfo = "----CUSTOMER INFORMATION-----";
     }else{
       custinfo = "";
       }

$("#comment").val(

//         "----CUSTOMER INFORMATION---- " +
     custinfo +
     domainn + 
     contact +         
     intlNumber +
     timez + 
     newemail +);
 }
```

Mi duda es cuando saco la impresion del Comment .val en me muestra ***Undefiend***.

Lo que necesito es que me pueda mostrar algo como +1 (305) 258-6986 (para telefono de US) o algo como +52 55-5721-3390 (para Mexico o paises con codigo de pais de 2 digitos) o algo como +593 99-9191919 (para Ecuador o paises con codigo de pais de 3 digitos).

Alguna sugerencia, por cierto estoy trabajando esto en AppScript de Google.

Gracias

Comment: has intentado usar un inneHTML ? aqui tienes un problema similar : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20604299/what-is-innerhtml-on-input-elements

Comment: ¿Cómo cargas jquery?

Comment: Puede que ese `+` que tengas extra al final del `val()` te genere el error